# error Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated when transfer site magento 1.9 server to localhost

Tags: php, magento, xampp, spl-autoload-register

I've been going crazy for days. I installed Windows Xampp on my PC and I copied my website (the whole folder from FTP) and the database in the htdocs folder.

Furthermore, the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php` does not exist, only 3 files called `Data`, `element` and `update`.

I have tried to use spl_autoload_register() instead, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any clue of what's wrong?

```
Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register() instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 60

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\Helper\Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home') 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index') 
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Cont in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 555
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using php7.2 on localhost.

That function is deprecated:

```
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php
```

You should change your PHP version to 5.6 locally for Magento 1.9 (unless you've upgraded it to work with 7.0)

Try using the same PHP version as you have on the live website.

Answer (score 0):

send the support notice the website works locally, but it is necessary to access the administration page of the backend and put the username and password reload the page but it does not enter. (if I put them wrong, he says they are wrong) ... I read the forms but also updated the cookies does not change the situation, not from any error.